# Footnotes in SVG files inserted as images

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I need to insert custom diagrams into the md file. I chose the SVG format as it is vector based as is the text. I insert it using `<img src=".\file.svg" />`.

The svg also contains plain text. Now I'd like to insert a footnote reference for the text that's contained within the svg. I tried using the `[^footnote1]` which doesn't work as it doesn't seem to parse. Ideally it would work just the same way as inserting footnotes in the normal text.

Any suggestions on how to do this and what parser to use?

Thx

Comment: How are you rendering your Markdown?

Comment: Using all the VS Code extensions I could find.

Comment: Those extensions are usually just for previewing. Where are these documents going to actually end up? You _might_ be able to get this working with an inline SVG, though that's a long shot. But it doesn't look like GitHub renders inline SVGs in READMEs, for example.

Comment: This is like a technical/academical document. It will end up on a web site, or as a PDF, or on printed paper. Inline, good idea. I guess it depends on the parser. Some of them ignore markdown in e.g. html contents. I'll test it in GitHub.

Comment: Markdown is a pretty basic format. For academia, LaTeX may be a better choice.